# I stole some furnaces from a village and a villager spawned at my house

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I was playing Minecraft (PS4 edition) and raided a village for anything and everything. I got home, placed my new furniture and now a villager has spawned in my house. He is from the desert village I stole the stuff from and there are no villages near my home. I can't find anything about this and don't know what happened. Can someone please explain why this keeps happening?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to know what caused the villager to spawn? If so, could you add that to your question?

Comment: How many doors and beds are there in your house?  Are there multiple buildings?